# How to implement SMS tracking in Twilio where multiple SMS been sent to the same number

Tags: sms, twilio-programmable-chat

We are implementing an SMS tracking feature for our app using Twilio where we will send an SMS to our customer and once they reply with Yes/No
we will take action accordingly. For normal case, where each customer has one single phone number we can easily track the replies and
take action. But if the customer use the same phone number for multiple accounts and we send multiple SMS to the same customer
(eventually in a same phone number) we are not able to track which specific SMS they have replied for.

Lets take an example,

User Tom has three accounts with us. Each of the three accounts uses the same phone number P.

Twilio SMS are tracked by a combination of From/To pair.

Assuming, we are using one Twilio proxy number as sending number which is S.

Case 1: Tom has one booking canceled for a short notice period. An SMS has been sent from S->P. When a reply is received, we can easily track the reply and take the action.

Case 2: Tom has two or more bookings canceled due to a short notice period.

For each canceled booking, an SMS has been sent from S->P. When the user replies, we are unable to detect which booking to mark the reply for.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to know which message a person has responded to in SMS. The only way to efficiently handle this is to send messages from different numbers. So, if a user signs up with the same phone number as another user then you need to assign a new Twilio number to them. Then you can tell which user you are contacting or receiving messages from by the number.

If you send out messages about bookings on the same account at the same time, then you need to be even more granular with the number access. Each notification should assign a number to use and then when a reply comes to that number it was about that notification. Then if you need to send a second message simultaneously, you attach a different Twilio number to it. And so on for more messages.